# C-s must be pressed twice

Tags: keyboard

I'm on macos Sierra (2013 Macbook Air). When I press C-s (control and the character s) nothing happens. Then, if I press it again (within a certain amount of time) it triggers. If I open the keyboard viewer in macos I can see that the s is not triggered until the second time it's pressed.

Any ideas on why it could be like this or how I can find out what is causing it?

Comment: Have you tried blowing-out your keyboard to make sure there's no crumbs or anything else in there that could be causing the connection to not work?

Comment: It’s not that. It _always_ works the second time. Unless I wait for X milliseconds. So there seems to be something that captures the first C-s and then waits for another keypress for a certain amount of time. Very odd.

Comment: Also, it happens with an external keyboard as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had khd installed which intercepted the C-s